# Is there any kind of API to get the co-occur number between two related tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, api, related-tags

With this API(https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-tags), I can only get the related tag's info on Stack Overflow, but what I want is the co-occur times. Like the following which is for tag "javascript":

> [image: this is from Stack Overflow which is for tag "javascript"]

Comment: What do you mean with the 'co-occur times'? The count of the tag is in the returned JSON, right?

Comment: ok, I got it wrong. I was thinking the field "count" is the number of questions that the related tag tagged. Maybe I have been misled by this sentence "This method returns a list of tags."

Comment: So you could just test it and see for yourself, like what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already get this in the API response:

> [image]

`count` represents the number of shared occurrences, as per the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-tags):

> `count` on tag objects returned is the number of question with that tag that also share all those in `{tags}`.

You need some programming to format it the way you want, you can't have the API return it with the design you asked for, only raw data from the database.

Comment: Yes, I did get it. I just understood wrong and thank you.